# Executing a prepared statement is not returning data

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I am creating Postgresql prepared statement as follows.

```
PREPARE fetch_users AS SELECT *
FROM "user" u
WHERE 
    u.email = $1
LIMIT 1;
```

It is getting successfully created, and I can see it in the `pg_prepared_statements` table.

But, when I do,

```
EXECUTE fetch_users('testemail@test.com');
```

I'm getting no result from the database, although the select query returns the result when run independently.

Am I using prepared statements correctly?

Note: I am using PostgreSQL version: `15.1` with Dbeaver. When I run the prepared statement I get this prompt.
[image]

I enter nothing for the value and select `Ok`. When the statement gets executed, this is the output.

[image]

It seems the null is inserted in the prepared statement.

Comment: Please show the definition of `fetch_user_list`

Comment: @Bohemian Actually, I mistakenly used a different name in definition. They are both `fetch_users`

Comment: Is it possible that you have two tables named "user" in different schemas?

Comment: @JimJones No I only have one table named "user". And, actually, `SELECT *
FROM "user" u WHERE u.email = testemail@test.com` is returning results. I am also using dbeaver to  execute the query. Not, sure if it has something to do with it.

Comment: @hermit strange... I cannot see how it could be wrong. Perhaps a whitespace? Have you tried `trim()`? just to make sure ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the prompt, you need to click on the ignore button:

[image]

This way it will not put any predefined parameter values in your prepared statements.